# Dreamweaver CS6 - How to convert latin caracteres to the correspondent html code?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I'm using Dreamweaver CS6, and when I write a latin word (**Transição** for example), I have problem with caracteres.

My question is: Is there a way, via hotkey in Dreamweaver CS6 to select a text and convert this text to html text?

For example, I Select:

`A transição foi concluída com sucesso.`

press a hotkey and the selected text is converted to:

`A transi&ccedil;&atilde;o foi conclu&iacute;da com sucesso.`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in function to do this in Dreamweaver.

**Option 1**

There is [this plugin](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=15427). You can select some text, and run this plugin from the "commands" menu.

I know this works CS5 but I have not tested it in CS6.

**Option 2**

If you change this line in your HTML file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

to this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

Dreamweaver will know to convert the characters automatically.

See [this forum here](http://www.webmaster-talk.com/html-forum/116056-converting-accented-letters-into-special-html.html).